# Load a graphics.Path from drawable resource (xml file in android studio)?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an XML definition of a Path in the android studio project (R.drawable.east_arrow). How can I construct an android.graphics.Path from this resource to use with Canvas.drawPath(..) ?

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? I have the same issue.